# Prove that if $A\in M_{mn}(\Bbb F)$ then $(A^T)^T=A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that if $A\in M_{mn}(\Bbb F)$ then $(A^T)^T=A$.

What I did: I took an arbitrary matrix $A$:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}& \ldots &a_{1n}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}& \ldots&a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I took $A^T$:

$$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{21}& \ldots &a_{m1}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{1n}&a_{2n}& \ldots&a_{mn}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And then I wrote:

$$(A^T)^T=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}& \ldots &a_{1n}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}& \ldots&a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}=A$$

My question is: is this even a proof?

Comment: Looks like a proof to me...

Comment: A totally valid proof

Comment: ... That's the definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will accept it as a proof, albeit it's far too tedious to my taste. You may simply state that $\left((A^T)^T\right)_{ij}=(A^T)_{ji}=A_{ij}$ for every $(i,j)\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}\times\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and hence $(A^T)^T=A$.

Comment: This is both a less tedious and more rigorous version of the proof...

Answer (score 2):

If $A=(a_{ij})_{ij}$, then $A^T=(a_{ij})^T=(a_{ji})_{ij} \text{ observe that i reverse the indices}$  *i.e.* in $A^T$ the element $a_{ij}^T=a_{ji}$. Now repeat the same argument:

$$(a_{ij}^T)^T=a_{ji}^T=a_{ij}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged proof-verification and proof-writing, I feel it should be said that although your argument would probably suffice to convince anybody that $(A^T)^T=A$ for all matrices $A$, it is not really a proof in a formal sense, as your rightly question. The point is, a proof is a succession of arguments leading to the claimed statement, but what you wrote does not contain any arguments at all, it is just a succession of sketches of what a certain matrix vaguely looks like. You end up claiming that the final display of a matrix is identical to the original matrix $A$, which amounts to the claim the the dots have to be filled in in the same way they are in $A$; understanding why this is so amounts to understanding that $(A^T)^T=A$ (yes, I see that if I try to visualise $(A^T)^T$ it should be the same as the original matrix $A$; but that is just evoking a mental picture, not an argument).

The approach can be made to a real proof though by specifying exactly what the dots represent. Two matrices are the same if they have the same dimensions, and if for every position $(i,j)$ inside that shape they have the same entry at position $i,j$. Write that out for $A$ and $(A^T)^T$, and you get identical descriptions; doing so constitutes a proof of the identity.

So while sketches and evocative descriptions may help us understand (see) why some result should (be expected to) be true, their inherent vagueness disqualifies them as elements of a formal proof. It may seem unjust to thus favour the left (formal) brain hemisphere over the right (more visually oriented) one, this is how things are done in mathematics. Of course there are better instances than the fairly trivial $(A^T)^T=A$ to illustrate why mathematicians rightly insist on precise and complete arguments.